# C++ where can I find the implementaion of BOOST_LOG macro in boost source package

Tags: c++, boost

C++  - where can I find the implementaion of BOOST_LOG macro in boost source package.
Just curious to see the imlementaion.

Can you please suggest me any possible command I can use in the boost source tree to locate such implementaion. Just curious to know the implementation.
I tried

grep -r BOOST_LOG * | grep define

this returns a whole lot of lines and I can't locate where exactly to look for this specific imlementaion.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/boost-1.68.0/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp#L570

Comment: When the question title contains the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would search the Boost documentation instead of the source tree. The [documentation for BOOST_LOG](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/log/doc/html/BOOST_LOG.html) says you are looking for the header `boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **Sublime Text**. It is worth the effort and time you put on to learning it. It is fast for navigation and search, and there are plugins like C++11 that direct you to function definitions and more.